# Swipe image views left and right like a drag and drop

Tags: android

I have an image view. I want to touch the image and drag it to left or right. When the image is dragged to the left, the new image should appear from the array. When i drag it to right it should be saved in another activity. How can i possibly do this, if somebody could guide me to a tutorial or example.  Thank-you

Comment: use a GestureDetector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewPager and PageAdapter.

```
protected class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public ImagePagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getImages().size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_page_view, null);
        String url = getImages().get(position);
        if (url != null) {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_page_view));
        }
        container.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
}

...
imagePager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                //logic to open activity or other action..;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
            }
        });

...
imagePager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter());
```